# Converting lat & long to javascript variables in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out.
I'm using phonegap to try and grab the current latitude and longitude and assigning the values to variables.

I'll be using the latitude and longitude in multiple locations within the app, so I need to assign it to a variable I can use elsewhere.

In this setup, the html output is "undefined".

I'm sure this has something to do with javascript and async that I'm missing... any help?

```
/******************** Life Cycle ************************/

function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

/******************** Device is Ready ************************/

function onDeviceReady() {


/******************** Geo Info ************************/

    // Variables
    var currentLat;
    var currentLon;
    var geoWatchID = 0;

    // get current geo location
    if (geoWatchID == 0) {
        var geoOptions = {maximumAge: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
        geoWatchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, geoOptions);

        function onSuccess(position) {
            currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
            currentLon = position.coords.longitude;
        }

        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

    } else {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(geoWatchID);
        geoWatchID = 0;
    }

    // display the current latitude and longitude w/ jquery
    $('#currLat').html(currentLat);
    $('#currLon').html(currentLon);

} // END device is ready
```

Anybody worked with this before?

Comment: It looks like I wasn't declaring the latlong as global variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `onSuccess` is invoked only after the jQuery statments, so try

```
    function onSuccess(position) {
        currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        currentLon = position.coords.longitude;

        // display the current latitude and longitude w/ jquery
        $('#currLat').html(currentLat);
        $('#currLon').html(currentLon);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
    function onSuccess(position) {
        currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
        currentLon = position.coords.longitude;
        update();    
    }

    function update(){
        // display the current latitude and longitude w/ jquery
        $('#currLat').html(currentLat);
        $('#currLon').html(currentLon);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, that's not what I'm looking for... I'm trying to get variables currentLat and currentLon used outside of onSuccess.  The jquery markers are only there to show if it's working or not.

Comment: I understand. But at the point of execution of the jQuery statements you have written, both `currentLat` and `currentLon` will be undefined. Then `onSuccess`  is invoked by the event and after that variables will be having the values eveywhere.

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Hope that helps you to understand it.

Comment: So How do I make it so other functions can use the currentLat and CurrentLon at different points in the code?  let's say I have a function called: "getBearing(currentLat,currentLon)" but, don't want to call the same point of onSuccess?

Comment: Yes you can call. But until `onSuccess` is invoked `currentLat` and `currentLon` will be undefined.

Comment: It's still not working the way I need it to. I need `currentLat` and `currentLon` working as global variables so I can pass them to functions that are called with `onClick` commands later.  onSuccess is called immediately when the page loads. `getBearing(currentLat,currentLon);` wouldn't fire until a button is clicked in the UI.  If I add getBearing() to the onSuccess function, it loads as soon as the page does. Make sense?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26115/discussion-between-troy-and-tracevipin)